# Export dataframe in pyspark to excel file given the 'openpyxl' module is not installed

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write my spark dataframes in an excel file to generate desired reports by changing them in pandas dataframe and then using

```
panda_df = df.toPandas()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)
panda_df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', startcol = 0, startrow = 0)
```

this gives an error saying

```
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pandas/io/excel.py", line 350, in __init__
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
ImportError: No module named openpyxl.workbook
```

I am running this on a remote server and hence do not have admin rights to use sudo apt-get as it says "Sudo: apt-get: command not found" and I have also tried using pip to no usage as it is not installed either. Is there any other way I can write my dataframes in excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows.

You can clone the library from it's source repository here:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl
```

Go into the openpyxl directory, then run the following to install it for your user without admin permission:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Then, you can add the path to the openpyxl to your code as follows:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/openpyxl/folder')

panda_df = df.toPandas()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename)
panda_df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1', startcol = 0, startrow = 0)
```

Comment: Hi I am not able to clone the repository.
"Initialized empty Git repository in /idn/home/sagar134/openpyxl/.git/
error: Couldn't resolve host 'bitbucket.org' while accessing https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/info/refs"     

This is what it says, then i tried ping which was not successful either so I am guessing my firewall has blocked the website?(Even though I can visit the website on browser). I found this link where they have marked it "Wont Solve" https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/6904/error-couldnt-resolve-host-bitbucketorg

Comment: @buddygyan if your firewall blocks access to internet, you can clone the repo on your local machine and ship it to the remote server as you are shipping the actual business code (maybe using filezilla or scp...)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use the Spark2 datasource of the HadoopOffice library (supports also Python). You can read/write Excel files that encrypted, linked to other workbooks, have metadata etc.
Furthermore, it has a low footprint mode, which enables you quickly writing of larger Excel files without requiring large memory amounts or CPUs:
https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/spark-hadoopoffice-ds

The datasource is based on the HadoopOffice library enabling virtually any Hadoop application to read/write Excel files, because it has corresponding Hadoop FileInputFormats and FileOutputFormats:
https://github.com/ZuInnoTe/hadoopoffice